# Proper Storage for Access Token in Client Credentials Authorization Grant in Meteor Js

Tags: api, meteor, access-token

I am creating an application using Meteor JS and get stuck on where to properly save my access token for client_credentials authentication grant.

Do I store it in Monggo DB?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing the access_token into Meteor Session and Checking if it exists and is not expired. If access_token is expired, generate again and store to Meteor Session.